# Installing emulator: hardware virtualization

Tags: emulation, win-universal-app, virtualization, windows-10-universal

When trying to install the Microsoft Emulator - Windows 10 for mobile I got the following error.  I have Intel VT enabled in my BIOS setting!

I need to run an UWP application on my Windows 10 Pro; how can I fix this?

[image: error screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

A typical error that many of us do when enabling Hyper-V is doing so from the BIOS and expecting it will work.

Hyper-V needs to be enabled on two different points:

- The BIOS settings.
- The operative system

The fun thing with Visual Studio is that, if hyper-v is not enabled on the OS, it still says that needs to be done on the BIOS settings.

The BIOS settings differ from manufacturers and versions, but the OS remains the same.

It is done so from the *Program and Features* option in the *Control Panel*; select the *Turn Windows features on or off* and then select the *Hyper-V* options from the dropdown.

Step 1:

[image]

Step 2:

[image]

Take into account that you need to be an Administrator in your PC as hyper-v needs to add users to the Admin group.
If you're working on a controlled environment, these options may be disabled by your company administrator.

Once everything is in place, you will need to reinstall the VM.